# Python, string in format of setting variables into variables

Tags: python

This is probably very simple, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I have a String:

```
str = "A = Test,\n B = 4, \n C = 100"
```

How do I turn this into the three different variables?

This is in python 3.

Comment: The correct question is "why?". You should avoid evaluating strings. Just use dictionary. `d = {"A": "Test", "b": 4, "C": 100}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the structure of your string looks simple, you can use the split method with several delimiters (using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) package). You can check if a variable can be converted into an int by casting an exception. I suggest to store the variables in a dictionary after then like this:

```
import re 

my_string = "A = Test,\n B = 4, \n C = 100"
list_of_string = re.split(' |,\n |, \n', my_string)

my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(list_of_string)):
    if (list_of_string[i] == '='):
        try:
            my_dict[list_of_string[i - 1]] = int(list_of_string[i+1]) 
        except:
            my_dict[list_of_string[i - 1]] = list_of_string[i+1] 

print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'A': 'Test', 'B': 4, 'C': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i am going to suppose that all your variable must be a str at the end.
You need to use the **exec** method.

exec() function is used for the dynamic execution of Python program which can either be a string or object code. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed unless a syntax error occurs and if it is an object code, it is simply executed.

for your program you could do this IF you can remove the spaces between the ',' and the name of your variables.

```
str = "A = Test,\nB = 4,\nC = 100"
text = str.split(",\n")
for element in text:
    name = element.split(" = ")[0]
    value = element.split(" = ")[1]
    exec(f"{name} = '{value}'")
print(A, B, C)

Output : Test 4 100
```